# How to keep a short word together with the rest of the sentence?

Tags: line-breaking

I'm writing an article. In a certain paragraph, the last sentence is spread over two lines. The second line is just a short word ('in') and that's a bit ugly.

Is there an easy way to keep it together with the rest of the sentence on a single line? I think about shrinking the space between the words or the characters.

Comment: put `\looseness=-1` before the start of the paragraph and TeX will try to make that para one line shorter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's a nice and easy solution! Thanks!

Comment: If `\looseness=-1` fails, use `~` before the trailing “in.” The `~` is good anyway before sentence ending prepositions and it won't interfere with `\looseness` (at least for the last line).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Which choice of line-breaking parameters gives the minimum number of lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168611/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put

```
\looseness=-1
```

before the start of the paragraph and TeX will try to make that para one line shorter, if the paragraph is long enough there is usually enough flexibility in TeX's linebreak algorithm to adjust the number of lines without exceeding the specified `\tolerance`.

Answer (score 2):

Use non-breaking space, i.e., "do~not~split". Use sparingly, I'd add such tweaks only in the last step before printing the definite version.