# Balance width of text

Tags: line-breaking

If I have some (normal paragraph) text that is only slightly longer than the page width, I get

*This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some

 text.*

How can I get latex to rearrange it to

*This is some text. This is some text. 

This is some text. This is some text.*

Essentially, I want to limit the stretch on the differences of length of the ends of the lines, without regard to the actual length.

Comment: I presume you want it auto-rearranged, without manual intervention on your part??

Comment: Yes, it would be pretty easy to just add a bunch of line breaks. But I have a lot of text.

Comment: Related: [Which choice of line-breaking parameters gives the minimum number of lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168611/5764)