# How do I shrink more letters/words into one line?

Tags: line-spacing

Basically, I'm looking for something like `\mbox` that won't break the document margins. I've tried using `\sloppy` but it didn't work.

[image]

Both example are just a screenshots - both texts are written with the same font size and use the same paper margins (template). However, the "right text" is shrunk into 5 lines while my text is for 6 lines - I just want to shorten my text into 5 lines as well. The whole document is written in two slopes.

Thanks

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to shorten/shrink spaces between words?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23921/5764)

Comment: Thanks, I've did my research here but it didn't work because the document I need to adjust has defined template (it probably doesn't allow such line adjustments) and it somehow did not compressed the spaces. Basically I need just half of the word which is divided to stay on one line without crossing the default margins.

Comment: Okay. Since you're working with some template for which the above reference doesn't work, can you please provide the community with the necessary means to replicate your current behaviour? That is, provide code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Can you do that?

Comment: ...this should include any reference to template files if we want to replicate it.

Comment: If you are typesetting using pdflatex try using the microtype package if you aren’t already doing so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. It might sounds kinda stupid when I'm looking for help but I can't share the template or the document due to the copyright and authorship. I was trying to get some idea whether you know any alternative that I might try.

Comment: @JoshE.: You can't even mock up something that replicates the behaviour? We're not interested in the information, just something that replicates it. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: I have extended the topic of what I'd like to achieve. Both are screenshots, so in the real document the font size is the same as well as the paper template.

Comment: @JoshE.: See [Which choice of line-breaking parameters gives the minimum number of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168611/5764) You could try with `\looseness=-1`.